# Mysqli select * from table where enum = x, y, or z

Tags: mysql

I want to count number of rows where and enum = anything but two values, but rather = 3 other values.

In my DB I have a enum with five different values, lets call them `A` `B` `C` `D` `E`, I only wnat to count the rows where enum = `C` `D` `E` but not where it = `A` or `B`. What is the best way to do something like this? Can I do something like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE enum >= C, D, E` or do I have to do it the hard way by `SELECT * FROM users WHERE enum = C, enum = D, enum = E`?

Comment: you tagged as mysqli with no code or API to support the question.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE enum = C, enum = D, enum = E` - that is an invalid statement. SELECT uses `AND|OR` as separators. Your other SELECT is also invalid. I suggest you go through all the manuals http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html --- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html  --- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- ye I didnt remember the properway way of doing it, but the point was if there was any easier way of doing it

Answer (score -2):

I think it's

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'enum' IN ('C', 'D', 'E')
```

Comment: 1.) enum is not a valid column name: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html - you have to escape this column name. 2.) double quotes not valid, you should use single quotes. 3.) second solution is not working C, D and E are not column names.